# Android notifyDataSetChanged() does not work

Tags: android, adapter, expandablelistview

I have read a lot of threads about this issue, but I cannot find a solution.

myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); (BaseExpandableListAdapter) for my ExpandableListView doesn't update it's built in method called: getChildView().

Thanks in advance!

Code:
This is my Adapter Class:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String title = (String) this.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            if ( groupViewType[groupPosition] == 0) {
                Log.d("MyAdapter", "getChildView: setting child_layout");

                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_layout, null);

            } else {
                Log.d("MyAdapter", "getChildView: setting exercise_layout");

                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.exercise_layout, null);

            }
    }
    return convertView;
}

   // To alternate between layouts when swiping to the right or left.
public void updateView(int groupPosition) {

    if (groupViewType[groupPosition] == 1) {
        Log.d("MyAdapter", "UpdateView: from 1 to 0");
        groupViewType[groupPosition] = 0;
    }
    else {
        Log.d("MyAdapter", "UpdateView: from 0 to 1");
        groupViewType[groupPosition] = 1;
    }
}
```

This is my MainActivity class in which I call MyAdapter:

```
expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expListView);
final MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this,  Headings, ChildList);
expandableListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            myAdapter.updateView(groupPosition); // This method works fine!
            myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  // It doesn't change the view in getChildView();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

SOLUTION:
I solved the problem by setting convertView = null; before the if statement in getChildView().

Sorry for asking.

Comment: What? You set it to null and then in the next line check if it is null? That seems counter intuitive...

Comment: Yes you are completely right haha. However, is there anything wrong with my method?

Comment: You really should be using the view holder pattern. While there is technically nothing wrong with this code, the view holder patter is best practice when using list view.  I highly recommend watching this Google IO talk about listview https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Comment: But in that case I cannot update the view in real time, right?

Answer (score 0):

You must use ViewHolder pattern for correctly work